# Vuetify custom v-text-field component is not updating the v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-model

I’m following this documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html
I created custom v-text-field component which looks like that:

```
<template>
<div>
<v-text-field
        :label="label"
        v-bind:value="value"
        v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"></v-text-field>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "txtbox",
    props: ['value', 'label'],
}
</script>
```

I implemented it in my main component almost succesfully:

```
<txtbox
label="Name"
v-model="eventName"
/>
```

I don’t think it is necessary to paste all the code, but if it is I will edit the post. Here is how it works:
I have a list, when i click on the list element the text-field displays content of it, this works fine. Sadly when I’m editing the content of text-field the v-model value is not updating. I can also add that it works fine with normal  (like in the docs) instead of . Is there anything I can do to make it work, or should i use simple input ?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you want to `$emit` the new value, you just have to emit the `$event`, and not `$event.target.value`

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-text-field
        :label="label"
        v-bind:value="value"
        v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"></v-text-field>
</div>
</template>
```

`v-on:input` can also be shortened to just `@input`

Comment: It works, thanks, but why there were no problems with normal `<input>` ?

Comment: That's because a normal input works differently than the `v-text-field`

Comment: @Jesper What a dude! I tried all sorts of convoluted implementations of a custom v-text-field, but this simple way has been the only one that works.